# Why is my all bootstrap accordion closing when I only close one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, accordion

My projects include some bootstrap accordion. I use collapse and show to allow the user to close each accordion by themselves. But now, when I close one of the accordions and reopen it, the others close in on it.

I added the bootstrap collapse and show classes so that the user can manually close each accordion. Initially, the entire accordion will remain open. I anticipate that all of the accordions will be turned on and off manually by the user. If I close or turn off any of the accordions manually, I don't want any other accordions to have any interaction (on/off). So if I turn off or open one accordion, the others should remain the same.

```
<style>

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

       .new-listing-head h1 {
           color: #000;
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 40px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 600;
           line-height: normal;
       }
       .listing-head-dropdown .dropdown-one .btn {
           padding: var(--25, 10px) var(--6, 24px);
           border-radius: var(--rounded-full, 1000px);
           border: 1px solid var(--primary-700, #1A56DB);
           background-color: transparent;
           color: #1A56DB;
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 500;
           line-height: 150%;
       }
       .listing-head-dropdown .dropdown-one:nth-child(2) {
           margin-left: 16px;
       }
       .dropdown-one .dropdown-toggle::after {
           display: none;
       }
       .listing-head-dropdown .btn {
           padding: var(--25, 10px) var(--6, 24px);
           border-radius: var(--rounded-full, 1000px);
           background: var(--primary-600, #1C64F2);
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 500;
           line-height: 150%;
       }
       .listing-head-dropdown .btn:nth-child(3) {
           margin-left: 16px;
       }
       .new-listing-head {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: space-between;
           align-items: center;
       }
       .listing-head-dropdown {
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
       }
       .listing-accordion {
           margin-top: 32px;
       }
       
       .listing-accordion .accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::before {
          transform: var(--bs-accordion-btn-icon-transform);
       }
       .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
           background-color: transparent;
           border: none;
           box-shadow: none;
       }
       .accordion-button:focus {
           box-shadow: none;
       }
    
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item {
           border: 0;
       }
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item .accordion-header {
           display: inline-block;
       }
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item .accordion-header .accordion-button {
           align-items: center;
           cursor: pointer;
           padding: 0;
       }
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item .accordion-header .accordion-button .listing-accord-head span:first-child {
           color: #000;
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 24px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 600;
           line-height: normal;
           display: block;
       }
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item .accordion-header .accordion-button .listing-accord-head span:last-child {
           color: #6B7280;
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 16px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 400;
           line-height: normal;
       }
       .listing-accordion .accordion-item .accordion-body {
           border-radius: var(--rounded-2xl, 16px);
           border: 1px solid var(--gray-200, #E5E7EB);
           background: var(--white, #FFF);
           margin-top: 16px;
       }
       .listing-search .form-control {
           border-radius: var(--rounded-lg, 8px);
           border: 1px solid var(--gray-300, #D1D5DB);
           background: var(--gray-50, #F9FAFB);
           border-left: 0;
           padding-left: 0;
       }
       .listing-search .form-control::placeholder {
           color: var(--gray-500, var(--gray-500, #6B7280));
       }
       .listing-search {
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
       }
       .listing-search .btn {
           border-radius: var(--rounded-lg, 8px);
           border: 1px solid var(--primary-600, #1C64F2);
           background: var(--primary-700, #1A56DB);
           color: #fff;
           white-space: nowrap;
           margin-left: 12px;
       }
       .listing-search .form-control:focus {
           box-shadow: none;
           border-color: #D1D5DB;
       }
       .listing-search .input-group-text {
           background: var(--gray-50, #F9FAFB);
           border: 1px solid var(--gray-300, #D1D5DB);
           border-radius: var(--rounded-lg, 8px);
           border-right: 0;
           border-top-right-radius: 0;
           padding-top: 10px;
           padding-bottom: 10px;
           border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
           padding-left: 14px;
       }
       .title-listing label {
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 500;
           line-height: 150%;
           color: var(--gray-900, var(--gray-900, #111928));
           margin-top: 18px;
       }
       .title-listing .form-control {
           border-radius: 8px;
           border: 1px solid var(--gray-300, #D1D5DB);
           background: var(--gray-50, #F9FAFB);
           padding: var(--3, 10px) var(--4, 16px);
           margin-top: 6px;
       }
       .title-listing .form-control:focus {
           box-shadow: none;
       }
       .description-listing {
           border-radius: 8px;
           margin-top: 20px;
       }
       .description-listing-btntwo .form-control {
           border: 0;
           width: 100%;
       }
       .description-listing-btntwo .form-control:focus  {
           box-shadow: 0 !important;
       }
    
       .nicEdit-panelContain {
           padding: var(--3, 7px) var(--4, 16px);
           padding-bottom: 10px;
           border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
           background: var(--gray-50, #F9FAFB);
       }
       .description-listing .form-control {
           border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
           border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
       }
    
       /* select and label */
       .listingdrop-select label {
           color: var(--gray-900, var(--gray-900, #111928));
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 500;
           line-height: 150%;
           margin-top: 16px;
           margin-bottom: 8px;
       }
       .listingdrop-select select {
           max-width: 348px;
           width: 100%;
           padding: var(--3, 12px);
           background-color: var(--gray-50, #F9FAFB);
           color: var(--gray-500, var(--gray-500, #6B7280));
           font-family: Inter;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-style: normal;
           font-weight: 400;
           line-height: 125%;
       }
       .listingdrop-select select:focus {
          box-shadow: none;
          border-color: #D1D5DB;
       }
       .listingdrop-description-select {
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
       }
       .listingdrop-description-select .btn {
           padding: var(--3, 6px) var(--6, 24px);
           padding-bottom: 10px;
           border-radius: var(--rounded-lg, 8px);
           border: 1px solid var(--primary-700, #1A56DB);
           margin-left: 16px;
       }
       .nicEditors {
           width: 100%;
       }
    
    </style>

    <div class="listing-accordion">
    
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <div class="accordion-header">
                  <div class="accordion-button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <div style="display: block; margin-left: 16px;" class="listing-accord-head">
                        <span>General Settings</span>
                        <span>analysis of order trends in one year</span>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <!-- Listing Search -->
                    <div class="listing-search">
                        <div class="input-group acounts-adress-input">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text adress-input-icon">
                                hi
                              </span> 
                            </div>
                            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us about your product. Enter a keyword, UPC, or ISBN to search">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn"> Search</button>
                    </div>
    
                    <!-- Title Listing -->
                    <div class="title-listing">
                        <label for="title">Tittle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bonnie">
                    </div>
    
                    <!-- Description Listing -->
                    <div class="description-listing">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
    
                    <!-- Description Select -->
                    <div class="listingdrop-select">
                        <label for="foldersave">Save to folder</label>
                        <div class="listingdrop-description-select">
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option selected>Save to Folder</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                            <button class="btn"><i class="fab fa-hippo"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
    
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Images -->
            <div class="accordion-item images-analysis">
                <div class="accordion-header">
                  <div class="accordion-button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsetwo">
                    <div style="display: block; margin-left: 16px;" class="listing-accord-head">
                        <span>Images</span>
                        <span>analysis of order trends in one year</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsetwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <div class="image-accordion-main">
                        <div class="images-analysis-content">
                            <img src="./image/image-a-one.png" alt="Listing Images">
                            <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn">
                                    hi
                                </button>
                            </div>
    
                         </div>
                         <div class="images-analysis-content">
                            <img src="./image/image-a-teo.png" alt="Listing Images">
                            <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="images-analysis-content">
                            <img src="./image/image-a-three.png" alt="Listing Images">
                            <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                                <button class="btn">
                                    hi
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                            </div>
    
                         </div>
                         <div class="images-analysis-content">
                            <img src="./image/image-a-four.png" alt="Listing Images">
                            <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                                <button class="btn">
                                    hi
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn">
                                    hi
                                </button>
                            </div>
    
                         </div>
                         <div class="images-analysis-content">
                            <img src="./image/image-a-five.png" alt="Listing Images">
                            <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn">
                                   hi
                                </button>
                            </div>
    
                         </div>
                         
                         <!-- Add New Image -->
                         <div class="newimage-analysis">
                            <img src="./image/addnew-image.png" alt="">
                            <div class="newimage-analysis-content">
                                <h5>Add New Image</h5>
                                <span>Max. File Size: 15 MB
                                    (jpg, png, heic)</span>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                     
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
    <script>
        // Disable the toggling behavior of Bootstrap accordion
        document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button').forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: FWIW all modern browsers default to JavaScript so you can remove the `type="text/javascript"` nowdays;

Answer (score 1):

The solution is far more simple. Just remove `data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"` from all accordion items. By doing so, accordion items become independent.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="listing-accordion">

    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <div class="accordion-button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <div style="display: block; margin-left: 16px;" class="listing-accord-head">
              <span>General Settings</span>
              <span>analysis of order trends in one year</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <!-- Listing Search -->
            <div class="listing-search">
              <div class="input-group acounts-adress-input">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text adress-input-icon">
                      hi
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us about your product. Enter a keyword, UPC, or ISBN to search">
              </div>
              <button class="btn"> Search</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Title Listing -->
            <div class="title-listing">
              <label for="title">Tittle</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bonnie">
            </div>
            <!-- Description Listing -->
            <div class="description-listing">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- Description Select -->
            <div class="listingdrop-select">
              <label for="foldersave">Save to folder</label>
              <div class="listingdrop-description-select">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                  <option selected>Save to Folder</option>
                  <option value="1">One</option>
                  <option value="2">Two</option>
                  <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn"><i class="fab fa-hippo"></i>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Images -->
      <div class="accordion-item images-analysis">
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <div class="accordion-button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsetwo">
            <div style="display: block; margin-left: 16px;" class="listing-accord-head">
              <span>Images</span>
              <span>analysis of order trends in one year</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsetwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <div class="image-accordion-main">
              <div class="images-analysis-content">
                <img src="./image/image-a-one.png" alt="Listing Images">
                <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="images-analysis-content">
                <img src="./image/image-a-teo.png" alt="Listing Images">
                <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="images-analysis-content">
                <img src="./image/image-a-three.png" alt="Listing Images">
                <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="images-analysis-content">
                <img src="./image/image-a-four.png" alt="Listing Images">
                <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="images-analysis-content">
                <img src="./image/image-a-five.png" alt="Listing Images">
                <div class="images-analysis-btn">
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                  <button class="btn">
                      hi
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Add New Image -->
              <div class="newimage-analysis">
                <img src="./image/addnew-image.png" alt="">
                <div class="newimage-analysis-content">
                  <h5>Add New Image</h5>
                  <span>Max. File Size: 15 MB
                      (jpg, png, heic)</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```